# Does batch activity add trigger on firehose?

Tags: getstream-io

The [Batch Activity Add](https://getstream.io/docs/js/#batch-activity-add) section of documentation says:

> The batch method doesn't trigger a fanout - therefore the followers of these feeds won't receive an update.

So it doesn't add it into the `followers`. But does it trigger the `Fire hose` or `web hooks`?

For Example. Will this activity trigger `web hook` or `fire hose` for all three notification feeds?

```
var feeds = ['notification:1', 'notification:2', 'notification:3'];
var activity = { 'actor': 'user:2', 'verb': 'pin', 'object': 'place:42', 'target': 'board:1' };
client.addToMany(activity, feeds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Our firehose will read only what's in the feed themselves, so if a feed does not get an activity then it won't show up on the firehose either.

For example, user A is followed by user B and user C. If user A adds an activity to their feed using the add-to-many batch endpoint, then user B and user C will not get the activity in their feeds, which means the firehose will **also not** get that activity.

Comment: So the origin where it is added will trigger only. And batch doesn't propagate activity so it doesn't trigger on follower feeds right?

Comment: Right, because the firehose will only get you activities in the following feeds, and the batch endpoint will not propagate the activities to followers.